# Extracting integers out from a string in Python without using re.findall

Tags: python

I have a string here:

```
test = "I saw 3 horses, 17 cat, and 14 rabbits!"
```

Now, without using `regex` and `lists`, I tried to extract integers from this string and find the maximum integer:

```
def largestNumber(text):
    largestNumber = 0

    for ii in range(len(text)):
        if text[ii].isdigit():
            if int(text[ii]) > largestNumber:
                largestNumber = int(text[ii])
        else:
            continue

    if noNumber(text):
        return None

    return largestNumber



def noNumber(s):

    for ii in range(len(s)):
        if s[ii].isdigit():
            return False

    return True
```

Unfortunately, this returns 7, which is the maximum integer, if you are looking at one digit at a time!

How do I fix this so that it detects 17 and not 7? Again, without using `regex` and `lists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a conversion routine on the split string you can then return the max value.

#### Code:

```
def to_int(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

#### Test Code:

```
test = "I saw 3 horses, 17 cat, and 14 rabbits!"
print(max(to_int(i) for i in test.split()))
```

#### Results:

```
17
```

Comment: good pythonic solution but `split` returns a list.  this sounds like a homework question where the prof is trying to get students to understand looping and accumulation.

Comment: Yep you are right, its a practice question for my programming class.  @jdigital

Comment: @jdigital, I agree, but basically I refuse to answer unlabeled homework questions with homeworky answers.  I am going to give pythonic answers. No time like the present to learn...

Answer (score -1):

If you are just interested in printing and not storing the values in a list:

```
words = test.split()
big = 0
for i in words:
    if i.isdigit():
        if int(i) > big:
            big = int(i)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

print(big)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 noregex.py
> 17
> ```

Comment: You said you are returning `7` and can't get `17`

Comment: No, your code is exactly the same as my code, why would it output `17` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180241/discussion-between-jasonbaik-and-vash-the-stampede).

Comment: I owe you an apology @JasonBaik when I pasted my code I didn't include copy over `words = test.split()` and then you were telling me it was outputting `7` when I was getting `17`, I got upset when the downvotes came in and acted like a child

Comment: @JasonBaik That was not acceptable behavior by me and then I insulted your code, I feel terrible but not embarrassed to admit I was wrong for attacking you, I apologize and deserve the downvotes plus some, very sorry :(